# Parsley Validation on a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, parsley.js

I've correctly applied Parsley to a few other forms already, but now I'm having an issue adding it to a simple Bootstrap 3 modal. I have a feeling it has something to do with adding data-parsley-excluded to the fields and then somehow having them reset when the modal is open. Here is my relevant code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Become Our Sponsor</h4>
                    <p class='small' style="margin-bottom:0px;">All fields are required.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="become-sponsor-form"  method="POST">
                        <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxx" />
                        <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxx" />
                        <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="x.xx.x.xx" />
                        <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning invisible mx-auto">
                            <p>Please fill out all required fields.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Kevin" data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-required data-parsley-excluded/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inf_field_LastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" placeholder='Bacon' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-required data-parsley-excluded/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inf_field_Email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="email" placeholder="kevinbacon@yourcompany.com" data-parsley-type='email' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-required data-parsley-excluded/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inf_field_Phone1">Phone</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inf_field_Phone1" minlength = '10' maxlength="14" data-parsley-error-message='Must be minimum of 10 digits' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-required data-parsley-excluded>
                            <input id="hidden-number" name='inf_field_Phone1' type="hidden" name="phone-full">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inf_custom_CompanyType">Type of Business</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="inf_custom_CompanyType" name="inf_custom_CompanyType" type="text" placeholder='Ecommerce, Marketing Agency, etc.' data-parsley-trigger='change' data-parsley-required data-parsley-excluded/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#become-sponsor-form').parsley().on('field:validated', function() {
            var ok = $('.parsley-error').length === 0;
            if (this.$element.hasClass('parsley-error')) {
                $('.bs-callout-warning').toggleClass('invisible', ok);

            };
        });
    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_button").click(function(e){

            var form_data = $("#become-sponsor-form").serialize();
            e.preventDefault();

             $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="loading_message text-center"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>');
             $.post("formaction.php", form_data, function(result){
                $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="success_message alert alert-success text-center" role="alert">Thank You.. We will contact you soon...</div>');
             });

            }
         )
})
</script>
```

Much of this is legacy code that I am trying to apply form validation to, so I'm having some issues reading what was already there (I'm relatively new). I'm sure there's a way to consolidate the two scripts into one clean script, I'm just not quite advanced enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Forgot to actually mention what the error is. The form is still able to submit even when I don't fill out any of the fields. However each individual form is validating correctly. 
Ex: it makes sure that the email address and telephone numbers are valid, however the form is still submitting, even with empty fields.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Having both `data-parsley-required` and `data-parsley-excluded` is contradicting isn't it?

Comment: @ShalinPatel I'm not getting any errors in the console. What's happening though is that the form is still able to submit, even when I don't fill anything out. I just realized I wasn't actually clear about what the issue was in the original post, sorry about that!

Comment: @rayt I think you're probably right, I just got to the point where I was trying out different things and forgot to remove -required.

Answer (score 0):

Got it all figured out, in case someone else runs across this issue!

This article from a different form validation plugin helped a bit: http://formvalidation.io/download/.

What I ended up doing was on page load, give the inputs `data-parsley-excluded`. Then in the script down below, add `data-parsley-required` and remove `data-parsley-excluded`. I also applied data-parsley-group to the inputs to be able to apply the isValid method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#become-sponsor-btn').on('click', function() {

            $("#inf_field_FirstName, #inf_field_LastName, #inf_field_Email, #inf_field_Phone1, #inf_custom_CompanyType").attr("required", true);

            $("#inf_field_FirstName, #inf_field_LastName, #inf_field_Email, #inf_field_Phone1, #inf_custom_CompanyType").removeAttr("data-parsley-excluded");

            $('#become-sponsor-form').parsley().on('field:validated', function() {
                var ok = $('.parsley-error').length === 0;
                if (this.$element.hasClass('parsley-error')) {
                    $('.bs-callout-warning').toggleClass('invisible', ok);
                };
            }); 
        });

        $("#become-sponsor-form").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#become-sponsor-form').parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
                var success = formInstance.isValid({group: 'block1'});

                console.log(success);
                if (success) {
                    var form_data = $("#become-sponsor-form").serialize();

                     $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="loading_message text-center"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>');
                     $.post("formaction.php", form_data, function(result){
                        $("#become-sponsor-form").html('<div class="success_message alert alert-success text-center" role="alert">Thank You.. We will contact you soon...</div>');
                    });

                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;                   
                }

            });
        });

    });


</script>
```